# How to recalculate IP checksum with scapy?

Tags: python, ip, spoofing, scapy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate a packet checksum without sending it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953371/how-to-calculate-a-packet-checksum-without-sending-it)

I've spoofed a source IP and MAC address in a captured packet, but now I need to recalculate the checksum so that it checks out once its been received (after being injected into the network of course). I didn't really want to implement the checksum myself, and I was thinking that `scapy` could do this for me. I read that the `show2()` function should recalculate the checksum, but I can't seem to get it to work.

So, how can I use `scapy` to recalculate (and replace) the checksum for a captured + spoofed packet?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, if there is another easy to use Python library that will work nicely in this situation - I'm all ears (eyes).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953371/how-to-calculate-a-packet-checksum-without-sending-it), you have to delete the `.chksum` attribute before calling the `show2()` method from `scapy`

Comment: I selected this answer because the key was that I had to `del` the chksum field. Previously I was manually rebuilding the packet with null bytes in the checksum field. Doing that and then calling `show2()` did not recalculate the checksum. Deleting the field first with `del` provides the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say for argument's sake that we're processing an IP header and want to recalculate the checksum after the next hop:

```
>>> iph = IP(import_hexcap())
0000 4500 0064 000f 0000 fe01 3726 c0a8 0108
0010 c0a8 030b
>>> iph.ttl = iph.ttl - 1
>>> del iph.chksum
>>> iph.show2()
###[ IP ]###
version= 4L
ihl= 5L
tos= 0x0
len= 100
id= 15
flags= 
frag= 0L
ttl= 253
proto= icmp
chksum= 0x3826
src= 192.168.1.8
dst= 192.168.3.11
options=
```

The `.chksum` field has your answer.